# how to read large json file on s3 to dataframe using sagemaker

Tags: json, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I tried using the code:

```
    from sagemaker import get_execution_role
    import pandas as pd
    
    bucket = 'xxx'
    data_key = 'TV.json'
    data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
 
    textfilereader=pd.read_json(
       data_location,lines=True,chunksize=1000)
    dflist=[]

    for df in textfilereader:
         dfList.append(df)

    df=pd.concat(dflist,sort=False)
```

error:sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Comment: What is the **full** error message.

Comment: i'd recommend using AWS Data Wrangler, which can read JSON from S3 and automatically convert to a dataframe: https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_json.html#awswrangler.s3.read_json